# Amazon's new feature that allows uploading pictures taken by device's camera - how?

Tags: javascript, android

Recently, Amazon website introduced new feature that allows uploading pictures taken by the device's camera:

[image]

When clicked, the standard Android's `Choose an action` dialog appears:

[image]

What approach/api is used to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iPhone iOS6 and from Android ICS onwards, HTML5 has the following tag which allows you to take pictures from your device:

```
 <input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
```

Capture can take values like camera, camcorder and audio.